# Django temporary merge other DB results with ORM

Tags: django, database, postgresql, merge, redis

This question seems to be very weird, but I'm very curious in how to solve this kind of issues.

The matter is that I have two different web platforms, lets say:

Platform A Local network application (Java based) with a dedicated OracleSQL db server.

Platform B Django with postgres SQL

All the systems are in local network.

So in platform B, there is some django views that requires aggregated data from system A, but this data is only needed per request basis.

I mean, the system A is a ERP software that have only the information about pricing of the products, and the platform B (django) have the product list itself.

So I need to create a view in django that lists the products, ordered by price. How this can be done?

I was thinking about querying django for the products, load the product list in a RAM storage, then ask to Platform A for the prices sending the product id array list, and then making a merge in RAM memory in order to generate a queryset ordered by price.

Could be REDIS any good for this purpose?

We have direct access to the OracleDB and also a specific endpoint service could be developed in Platform A. Lets say a API-JSON endpoint.

In order clarify my question, the data flow could be:

Request: Give me the products

```
-> PlatformB <-> getPrices() <-> PlatformA
PlatformB:Products | Prices:PlatformA
<- result <- PlatformB
```

The question is how to get this PlatformB:Products | Prices:PlatformA in a performance way.

Thank you very much for your time,

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

If the endpoint that actually delivers the merged data is in B (the django based app), you could as you have already proposed:

1. create an REST endpoint in A to fetch product data per ID like http://a-host/products/[pk]/prices.
2. When Djange gets a request for a product + prices it fetches the product data using the REST endpoint from A. You can add decent cache headers (in A) and use caching (in Django) to reduce the requests towards A. Cache times depend on how often prices are updated and whether they are personalized per user.

This also requires that Django and A know of the same product IDs.

---

Alternatively, loading the data into Redis as you yourself proposed would also be an option. All the more if you already have a Redis that is accessible by both A and B, and if product data is quite stable. For example, if products are loaded once a day and you can just reload the data in Redis right afterwards.

This is mostly PK lookup with high performance. It's not the best option if you need searchable products.

It also requires that both A and B use the same product IDs, and the product ID is known during request time.

---

As a 3rd option, if you need searchable, sortable, filterable data, and high performance:

You could load everything into a search index like SOLR or Elastic, already completely prepared in the structure that you need it delivered. This will allow you to search on product names, have auto complete, facetting, sorting, paging on the resulting structure etc. Especially facetting (aka aggregation in Elastic) is something you might find useful.

It also would move the time consuming work to an import process and relieve the requests from it. During the import process you could align the data if A and B do *not* use the same product IDs.

---

You have not provided that much information on the system to really decide what is a good solution for your environment, data and use cases.

Comment: thank you very mutch for your response.

The thing is that I need the princing information on the Platform B (django) because this have the web frontend where the products/prices will be presented.

The Elasticsearch solution could be an option..